# Nginx not redirecting to https from http

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

This is common problem but I cant seem to find the solution and been on this problem for last 4 hours.

Nginx

```
upstream hype {
    server hype:7171;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.xyz www.example.xyz;
    return 301 https://example.xyz$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.xyz www.example.xyz;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;
    


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hype;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

Going to http works and shows

[image]

Its not redirecting to https
and when i try to add https manually

[image]

DNS setting on digital ocean
CNAME [www.example.xyz](http://www.example.xyz) is alias of example.xyz
A record for example.xyz

Answer (score 0):

you have other config in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. You need to remove the default server config first

Comment: No, there is no nginx folder in /etc

Comment: where did you install nginx? it may be /usr/local/nginx.